# MySQL casting from decimal to string

Tags: mysql, casting

Why doesn't the `CAST` work in this MySQL query?

```
SELECT  MAX(Signups) AS Max, 
        MIN(Signups) AS Min,
        CAST(ROUND(AVG(Signups),2) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS Avg
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS Signups,
    DATE_FORMAT(JoinDate, "%Y-%m-%d") AS Date
    FROM users
    GROUP BY Date
) z
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'VARCHAR(3)) AS Avg FROM ( ' at line 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be due to [MySQL bug #34564: CAST does not accept varchar type](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34564).

Try casting to a different type, like this:

```
CAST(ROUND(AVG(Signups),2) AS CHAR(3)) AS Avg
```

Comment: Note that this was the first Google result for "mysql cast to varchar", and I found it within seconds.

Comment: I did not know varchar was the issue hence I did not use your search term to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Nai: But it's what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

Changing `VARCHAR` to `CHAR` solves the problem